# Buddypress avatar image in database

Tags: database, mysql, buddypress, user-meta

I want to get path of buddy-press profile pic directly in database to be used on other then word-press platform but i am not able to find it in database.. because i can't use buddy-press functions in other platform or language.i am using only buddypress databse.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuddyPress does not store the avatar path in the database.

It loads avatars using the directory path - usually `.../wp-content/uploads/avatars/`.  For example, the full sized avatar for a member might be `.../wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/ef1e70a512662ea4fdca5b2efb6f76ab-bpfull.jpg` where `1` is the user_id.

Check your BP installation to find the exact path to the avatars.